# ESLint error in version 8.8.0 - "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] Must use import to load ES Module"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, package.json, eslintrc

So I've been following the front-end masters "Intro to React, v7" course, and in it, there is a portion of the course dedicated to installing ESlint locally within a React project (which isn't using create-react-app).

After installing ESlint to my project and trying to run the command `"eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet"` I receive this error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
    
    ESLint: 8.8.0
    
    Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\universal.js
    require() of ES modules is not supported.
    require() of C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\universal.js from C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
    Instead rename universal.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\package.json.
    
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1149:13)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
        at require (C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
        at Object. (C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:27:9)
        at Module._compile (C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\Completed portfolio sites\My portfolio\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
```

My `package.json`

```
{
      "name": "my-portfolio",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
        "format:check": "prettier --check \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
        "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
        "lint:fix": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --fix"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "eslint": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
        "events": "^3.3.0",
        "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
        "parcel": "^2.3.2",
        "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "url": "^0.11.0",
        "util": "^0.12.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
      }
    }
```

My `.eslintrc.json` config file (located in src/ folder):

```
    {
        "extends": [
          "eslint:recommended", 
          "plugin:import/errors", 
          "plugin:react/recommended", 
          "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended", 
          "plugin:react-hooks/recommended", 
          "prettier"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "react/prop-types": 0,
          "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0
        },
        "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y", "react-hooks"],
        "parserOptions": {
          "ecmaVersion": 2022,
          "sourceType": "module",
          "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
          }
        },
        "env": {
          "es6": true,
          "browser": true,
          "node": true
        },
        "settings": {
          "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
      }}
```

I'm really not sure what is causing this error, as I have gone back and picked through the course videos to see if I missed anything (which I didn't). My only guess as to what is causing this error is either a package not being in the correct version (version conflicts), or something not being installed correctly (although all of my package versions/installs match the ones used in the course videos).

I'm quite new to npm packages (ESlint especially), so I'm not sure if I forgot to include some configuration somewhere. If anyone has any suggestions to how to fix this please let me know...this is bothering me!

**Update**

So I managed to fix this issue, and it turns out it was due to my installed Node version being out of date. I was using Node v12.18.x, and upon updating to v16, the problem went away. I realized when installing some nvm packages that I was receiving warnings that my node version was behind the required version for certain packages, thus giving me the inkling that my installed Node version might be the problem.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer as an edit to the question, please [post it as a self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/6243352).